# IntelliJ share code formatting settings in git repository

Tags: git, scala, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I do not want to commit the IntelliJ project file/folder to my git repository but I *do* want to share the formatting settings.

Ideally in a way such that IDEA automatically picks them up when opening the project after freshly checking it out so that me and my fellow colleagues can have a good time coding without worrying about the code style.

We're talking about a Scala project.

Comment: In may projects I use File->Export Settings (Choose what you want) to get jar file with formatting style. And I share this jar trough the email with the all team mates.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

http://editorconfig.org/

It's language agnostic and supported not only by Idea, but by Eclipse and e t.c.

Answer (score 0):

in Intellij you have File > Export Settings. But it seems it contains not only the formatting but highlight, plugins and etc..